# What are the approaches we can follow to define a timer-job-liked which checks our sharepoint online lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, email, timer-jobs, schedule

I have a couple of sharepoint online lists which have a custom column named "Project Due Date" of type Date-time. Now i want to run a scheduled job on daily basis (12:00 am) which will check if the "Project Due Date" is within next week, and send an email to a group of users inside a SharePoint group accordingly. then after sending the email, to update a checkbox inside the list item indicating that an email has been sent (to avoid duplicate emails on next day).

if i am inside a SP-Onpremises environment, i will do this by creating a console application + schedule its execution using windows tasks scheduler.

but inside sharepoint online, what are the best appraoch to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: for the user who request to close this question.. now i am NOT asking for opinions i am asking about appraochies...

Comment: Have you considered using workflows? You can have the workflow pause for x days, so you'll have to calculate how many days to pause the workflow.  The only thing is, this approach wouldn't send emails at midnight but the time the item was created.

I would personally use the approach in @Sergei's answer (in fact I've got a few jobs I've been running for years with no issue) but figured I'd give you an alternative.

Comment: @wjervis i heard before about Pause Until inside workflow, but i read that they have many drawbacks, such as modifying the date will not get reflected. now i am not sure if this have been improved in SP online. if i find an appraoch to achieve what i am looking at using workflows, then this will remove the headache of developing and hosting the console application . could you advice more on your choice of using workflow? is this appraoch reliable ? and will it be capable to handle modifying the Due Date?? also does pause until means the item can not be edited (the item is paused)?

Comment: I'd not recommend workflows for this scenario.  I just figured I'd mention it as a last-ditch alternative.  As you say, there are flaws with this approach that aren't worth the effort.  I'd personally go with an Azure Job, as suggested by Sergei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run your job in any cloud-based service, which supports scheduled runs. It might be AWS (Amazon Web Services) or Azure. Azure is a better choice because it's .net based, Microsoft backed, has a lot of convenient SDKs and this approach is proven by many SharePoint developers\companies.

In **Azure** you have two options: go with Azure Function or with Azure web jobs.
Azure jobs have a higher cost in comparison to Azure Functions.

**Azure Functions** have a free tier, which gives you approximately 100hours with 1GB memory or 200 hours with 512MB of memory per month for a function running 1 sec or 3.3 hours with 512MB of memory per month for a function running 1 minute. An Azure function can't run more than 10 minutes, that's a drawback. If there is a chance, that your timer jobs run more than 10min, then go ahead with Jobs.

For **Azure Jobs** you have to select always on mode, which will cost at Basic level approx. 50$ per month.
In general, if money doesn't matter I suggest using jobs for such tasks. Why? Because Functions are more for serverless approach, with different triggers and dynamic flows. Also, Web Jobs sdk a lot more stable and friendly. Azure Functions are still changing some things, which might be confusing at start.

Must read articles - [PnP remote timer job framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-remote-timer-job-framework)

One another approach through using your own on-premises infrastructure, which has internet access. However I believe it's even more difficult and costly to implement than cloud-based solution.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and helpful reply. so for both options Azure Function + Azure jobs, will I be able to link them with a .net console application which integrate with sharepoint REST API to query the list items + check/Update their DueDate + Send email? is this possible? second question i have, now the console application size will be less than 1 MB, and should not take more than 5-10 minutes on worst cases scenarios... but not sure what are the time and memory limitations you mentioned you said `gives you approximately 100hours with 1GB memory or 200hours with 512MB of memory`?

Comment: Yes, in both Functions and Jobs you are able to run a .net code, which sends rest api queries. and do almost whatever you want. For `#2` - I meant Azure functions pricing. You can select how many memory your function uses, based on memory total price will be calculated. Check out [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator) - add Azure Function, select memory size, number of executions and see your total price. Very handy tool.

Comment: thanks for your reply. now i read this article about Azure Functions (https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-scheduled-executables/).. but i am not sure if i can use a standard .net console application? as in the link they are using  a file named `function.json` inside the console application.. which standard console application dose not have it by default + is there a UI to configure the trigger schedule for Azure functions as in the on-premises windows tasks scheduler case??

Comment: `function.json` is a requirement for azure functions, this file describes essential parts and some configuration of a function. There is no UI for building schedule, however, azure funcs use cron scheduler, so you can use any online cron expression builder.

Comment: and what about the actual code?  now i have my console application already created inside my VS 2015 professional, and i can run it from my PC and it integrates with sharepoint list using REST API , then it sends an email.. so can i upload the console application as-is inside Azure function? and then schedule it to run each day @1:00 am?? or i can not simply upload my current console app to Azure function.. not sure looks like i am unable to get my head around Azure functions...

Comment: Checkout [this](https://www.francoisdelport.com/2018/02/how-to-run-console-applications-on-a-schedule-on-azure-functions/) article or search similar

Comment: i find also this article which seems what i need to do exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348498/run-exe-executable-file-in-azure-function is this correct?

Comment: right, this SO answer even better. Try with something really simple first, like Console.WriteLine in your console app, just to make sure everything works at the minimal level of code

Comment: and i should be able to send email from my console application which is hosted inside Azure function? second point looks like the .exe file does not have the standard Main method which my console application have.. or this is not an issue?

Comment: it's not an issue, just use upload your console as-is